# quickblox ios push notifications messages issue

Tags: ios, quickblox

Can we post a pic from ios push notifications messages using quickBlox sdk? any body help.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean 'post a pic'?

Comment: @Igor yes,i want know can we post a pic under push notification

Comment: post a pic mean post image to other user in quick blox

Comment: we can post link to an image inside push, than user will be able to download it. Is it OK for u?

Comment: is Rich Push not working for ios?

Comment: it works! just upload image to Content and send Push with file ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload image to Content module & send it in push

```
NSData *file = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YellowStar" ofType:@"png"]];
[QBContent TUploadFile:file fileName:@"Great Image" contentType:@"image/png" isPublic:YES delegate:self];

- (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{

    // success result
    if(result.success && [result isKindOfClass:QBCFileUploadTaskResult.class]){
        QBCFileUploadTaskResult *res = (QBCFileUploadTaskResult *)result;
        int uploadedFileId = res.uploadedBlob;

        // Send push with file ID
        NSString *mesage = @"Hello man!";

        NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
        [aps setObject:mesage forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
        [aps setObject:@uploadedFileId forKey:@"file_id"]; // this is file ID
        [payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];

        QBMPushMessage *message = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];

        [QBMessages TSendPush:message toUsers:@"45288" delegate:self];
    }
```

Comment: In this Example its give warning on int uploadedField. and         [aps setObject:@uploadedFileId forKey:@"file_id"]; this line give error.

Comment: just convert from int to string and pass

Comment: can we send image also when we are registering new user